# What's the difference between communality & communalities in factor analysis?

Tags: r, factor-analysis

When you get EFA result `a<-psych::fa()`,you can find 2 similar parameters:`a$communality` and `a$communalities`,they are slightly different.
What's the difference between them?

Comment: Did you look at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.7.5/topics/fa ?

Comment: yes but don't understand communalities

Comment: Are you using `fm="minrank"`? If so, why?

Comment: when you use `fm='minres'`,you still get a$communalities.